# Stuck Trying to Pass Core Data from a Table View Controller to a View Controller - not getting any values to pass

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a TableViewController displaying core data that I am trying to pass to another view controller when the user selects a certain row.  I'm not sure why this is not working. I have looked and looked at the code which seems right - but the data to be passed is not populating - in my prepare for segue - there is no data and the view Controller loads with nothing in it.  Any help to "fix" what I am missing here is much appreciated!

TableViewController Code (Source)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation

class MyEventsTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var myEvents:[myEventsData] = []

var fetchResultController: NSFetchedResultsController!

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject!,atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath!){

    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

    default:
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    myEvents = controller.fetchedObjects as [myEventsData]

}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "myEventsCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyEventsTableViewCell

    let eventData = myEvents [indexPath.row]
    cell.eventNameLabel.text = "Name: " + eventData.eventName
    cell.startDateLabel.text = "Start: " + eventData.startDate
    cell.endDateLabel.text = "End: " + eventData.endDate

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()



    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue (segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showEventDetails" {

        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as MyEventDetailsViewController
        if let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForCell(sender as MyEventsTableViewCell) {
            let object = fetchResultController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? myEventsData

            destination.name = object?.eventName
            destination.start = object?.startDate
            destination.end = object?.endDate

        }
        }
}
```

ViewController Code (Destination)

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class MyEventDetailsViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var eventName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var startDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var endDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var details: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var postComment: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var checkIn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var addPhoto: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var myWineJournal: UIButton!

var name: String?
var start: String?
var end: String?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    eventName.text = name
    startDate.text = start
    endDate.text = end


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/iMac239/CoreDataSegueDemo

Comment: its helped a lot - that's actually exactly what I am using - so I am still not sure what I am missing as I tried to follow that exact code

Comment: Then there has to be something wrong with the code you manipulated because that project seems to work fine. Can you include your code for your fetchedResultsController?